# How would one split content of a post into pages?

Tags: plugins

I would like to know if anyone see a nice plugin that split long posts into multiple pages. the posts are about 20 pages long. so, Preferably if the navigation look like this:

**Previous Page | Currently Viewing Page of "Total Page" | Next Page**

if anyone can write the plugin, it would be a kind of you.

Comment: Are you looking for the `<!--nextpage-->` tag per chance?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a plugin for that, it is built-in. Just insert `<!--nextpage-->` where you need the break, and a properly coded theme will create pagination links.

To create page links in a theme use [`wp_link_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages)

Screen shot back-end:
[image]

Screen shot front-end:
[image]

Comment: It's working fine but when more then 50 pages thats time user not known whats is on 35 page so how to generate index?